# How do I make the Unity launcher show up on the left hand screen?

Tags: unity, launcher

I use two monitors and the Unity Launcher appears on the right hand screen by default. How can I force the launcher to appear on the left hand screen?

Answer (score 3):

Click the shutdown/settings gear, then "Displays". Use the "Launcher placement" dropdown to select which monitor(s) you want the launcher on.

Answer (score 0):

I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 and I use two monitors as well. I had the same problem and there has got to be a better way, but... I just played around in x-server until I got the launcher on the right hand screen. Like, set up x-server as if your monitors were reversed and then move them back to the correct positions. I also fiddled with the "Make this the primary display for the X screen" check-box. Not a very elegant solution, but it did work.